# Dynamically add HTML and call modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a piece of HTML dynamically to my body, and then use that to show a modal window. The `modal.html` is an exact copy of the example on the Bootstrap 4 site:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="dlgModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I load this using this code:

```
$('body').append("modal.html");
```

When I check if the ID exists, I do find an object in the developer's console, but calling `modal()` on it has no effect:

```
» $("#dlgModal")
← Object { context: HTMLDocument http://127.0.0.1/index.html, selector: "#dlgModal" }

» ​$("#dlgModal").modal()   /* nothing happens */
```

How can I load the HTML via Javascript and then call the bootstrap method on it?

Comment: this is a plugin isn't it ? Why don't you use vanilla js instead?

Comment: @WilliamBright because I decided to use Bootstrap and jQuery.

Comment: yes but this isn't straight jQuery or Bootstrap this is some other package that builds on top, isn't it? That's all I'm asking. So maybe clarify what it is youre using to help people understand the issue.

Comment: @WilliamBright no, this is all straightforward Bootstrap and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed some calls up. I had to use `load()`, but doing that in my `body`, would remove everything that was already there, so I added a container:

```
$('body').append("<div id='messageboxContainer'></div>");
$('#messageboxContainer').load("modal.html");
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you are executing i.e. `$('body').append("modal.html");`, will simply add a text node 'modal.html' as a child of body. It will not load the 'modal.html' file from your server.

Assuming, that the `modal.html` file is served by your server at `<hostname>/modal.html`, your JS should be something like this:

```
$.get('/modal.html', function(content) {
    $('body').append(content);
});
```

`$.get('/modal.html')` loads the 'modal.html' file from your server. The callback function is executed when the file is loaded from server, at which point you can append the returned content to 'body'.

PS: To show the modal you'd need to pass a string `'show'` to `.modal` function. eg. `​$("#dlgModal").modal('show')`

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, your usage of `.append()` is incorrect as in your example it would literally just output the text 'modal.html'.  Your trigger to load the modal will also fail because you're loading the modal HTML template outside the DOM.  A simple solution would be as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'modal-template.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('body').append(data);
    $("#modal-id").modal();
  }
});
```

In the above code we're using jQuery's built-in AJAX support to load your HTML template. On a successful load we're taking that information as `data` and appending it to `body`.  At that point your modal and its relevant ID now exist within the Dom, so we trigger the modal.

My *personal* preference however, is to have a 'shell' modal inside the default HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="your-modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From there you insert the content into the modal as needed via the following jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(event) {
  var m_target = $(this).data("target"),
      m_path = $(this).attr("href");

  $(m_target + ' .modal-content').load(m_path); 
});

$('#your-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this).find('.modal-content').empty().html('');
  $(this).modal('dispose');
});
```

The first bit allows you to load modal content into your existing, blank Modal template.  The second ensures that when the modal is closed it is properly emptied out, which alleviates a potential issue where the next modal trigger might load the cached / old information (especially if you link to an invalid URL).  Like I said... this method is simply my preference because it keeps an ID that is already part of the DOM.  It's also a little more flexible (again, opinion only) as you can pass additional data attributes to it.  In my normal usage I also pass along a size attribute to determine how large the Modal should be.